# what does line of code mean: inputArray[0]

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to understand what it means when a code appears in between the brackets. I know that has something to do with an array.

Comment: index 0 of an array variable named `inputArray`, please read a tutorial about arrays...

Comment: what is the context?

Comment: @MarkMeyer this is not covered in the linked dupe.

Comment: `[1] == ([1])[0]`

Answer (score 2):

In the case of "inputArray[0]", it is finding the value at index position 0 (the first element) in the array "inputArray".